# AngularJS change class for 1 element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want change the class to the same element when i click on him. For the moment, all classes changes. I miss something...

**HTML Part**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h4>Location</h4>
  <div ng-class="class" ng-click="changeToogleState(filter.value)" ng-repeat="filter in filters">{{filter.name}}</div>
</div>
```

**JS Part**

```
$scope.class = 'filter';
$scope.changeToogleState = function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  $scope.class = ($scope.class == 'filter') ? 'filter-active' : 'filter';
}
```

Thanks for your help.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waeoeP

Comment: ng-repeat creates a child scope. You need to follow the dot rule. For this element do this.class.

Comment: **TRY:** this.class = (this.class == 'filter') ? 'filter-active' : 'filter';